# Selection of prior for bayesglm

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, prior

I am using the `bayesglm()` function in R on medical data with 5% positive cases and 95% negative cases in the binary response variable.  I have 20 explanatory variables, both continuous and categorical. I am wondering what the best method of prior selection is.  I know I can use normal, t or Cauchy prior distributions but I am unsure how to figure out which works best.

Any help on what would be best, or on what to do to figure this out would be great.